# How to check if two python queues are identical

Tags: python, queue

I want to create a function that checks if two given queues are identical. I know how to set up a queue class and its methods but im not sure how to check two queues for being identical.

I'm thinking of using dequeue() and recording the returned values then comparing them but im not sure how to put this in a loop.

For example, how would I check to see if `["A",2,"David",4]` and `["A",22,"David",4]` were identical? 
This is what I have so far

```
def queue_is_identical(source1,source2):
    result = 0
    while result == 0:
        src_1 = src_1.dequeue()
        src_2 = src_2.dequeue()
        if src_1 != src_2:
            result == False
    if self.source1.isempty()==True:
        return result
    return result
```

Comment: please give us two examples for queues that you are comparing. thanks.

Comment: If you want help with your queue class, we'll need to see your code.  Comparing two queues is generally doing an element-by element comparison.  Are the queues equal if their elements are different instances, but containing the same values?

Comment: They have to be the same values in the same order.

Comment: Oh, I read that dequeue() is the same thing as pop() but pop() is what im trying to go for (something to remove an element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using python queues:

```
from queue import Queue

def queue_is_identical(source1,source2):
    return source1.queue == source2.queue

source1 = Queue()
source2 = Queue()
for item in ["A",2,"David",4]:
    source1.put(item)
for item in ["A",22,"David",4]:
    source2.put(item)
print(queue_is_identical(source1,source2))
```

Comment: My bad, I meant queues but wasn't sure how they are shown

Comment: It appeares that `dequeue()` is not a python queue function.  If you defined your own queue it is likely using the `queue.pop()` function.  Doing an itemized compare is likely to take the longest, so I would suggest doing above.